# map array of object by property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this (says it's Object A)

`[{grade:1},{grade:2},{grade:3}]` till 100th.

how to map this existing data (says its name is object B) into them?

```
[
{grade:1,name:'alice',address:{poscode:123},tel:324}
{grade:5,name:'wonder',address:{poscode:123},tel:1234223},
{grade:90,name:'james',address:{poscode:234},tel:324}]
]
```

Says grade 50, it doesn't match any of Object B, the final result should also have the name and address property, assign the value null to them to make the array consistent. I issue is what if there's other property in Object B if I loop using Object A?

Comment: Use the Array method... `map`?!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you can use Object A as your map source, then use Object.assign to copy individual properties from Object B as well as adding in some defaults:

```js
const objA = [{grade:1},{grade:2},{grade:3}];
const objB = [
{grade:1,name:'alice',address:{poscode:123},tel:324},
{grade:5,name:'wonder',address:{poscode:123},tel:1234223},
{grade:90,name:'james',address:{poscode:234},tel:324}
];
const objC = objA.map(rootObject => Object.assign(
    // A new object with some defaults
    { name: null, address: null, tel: null },
    // The source object from objA
    rootObject,
    // The data object from objB, if any
    objB.find(detail => detail.grade === rootObject.grade)
  )
);
console.log(objC);
```

Comment: imagine besides name, address and tel I have tons of other properties.

Comment: @Mellisa Then you should either put them in `objA`, or else add them to the defaults object. I mean, assuming you had no *grade 1* in `objB`, how would the map function know what fields subsequent `objB` entries could have. You need to store a finite list of defaults somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using convenient Array methods. See snippet below:

```js
const a = [
  {grade: 1},
  {grade: 2},
  {grade: 3},
  {grade: 4},
  {grade: 5},
  {grade: 90},
  {grade: 100}
];
const b = [
  {grade:1,name:'alice',address:{poscode:123},tel:324},
  {grade:5,name:'wonder',address:{poscode:123},tel:1234223},
  {grade:90,name:'james',address:{poscode:234},tel:324}
];

let result = a.map(aItem => {
  let match = b.find( bItem => aItem.grade === bItem.grade );
  if(!match){
    return Object.assign({}, aItem, { name: null, address: {}, tel: null });
  } else {
    return match;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Keep in mind if you use `aItem` as the first parameter to `Object.assign`, you modify Object A.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that

Comment: what if I have other property besides name and address and tel?

Comment: Well, you just have to create defaults (null) for every one of them.